# How to sum reference into one row if multiple rows contains reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a tricky issue. I want to sum total hours worked in a week for a person, but the datasource includes multiple rows of timecodes for the same person (see attached photo, 1). I want to be able to sum the hours for each week, so I get one row per person (see attached photo, 2)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use SUMIF() by Resource column.

Answer (score 0):

**This solves the issue:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Array (CSE) formula in Cell `A27` to  get Unique name list, fill it down.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$16:$A$24, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$26:A26, $A$16:$A$24), 0)),"")}
  ```
- Enter this formula in Cell `k27` & fill down.

  `=IF(SUMIF($A$16:$A$24,A27,$K$16:$K$24)=0,"",SUMIF($A$16:$A$24,A27,$K$16:$K$24))`

**Edited:**

- You may use this formula also:

  ```
  =IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$16:$A$24=A27)*($F$16:$I$24))=0,"",SUMPRODUCT(($A$16:$A$24=A27)*($F$16:$I$24)))
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Thank you for your answers! The formula works- thank you. Allthough I forgot to mention that the datasource will be updated once a week. Therefore I will have to sum by week, but with just one row per person. 

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Glad to help you @Ballefrans,, method will be similar,, you may work with a person or many and as time suits ,, if you are looking to automate formula based on Time interval then you need to program it (VBA macro). *Since my formula works for you then you may accept it as Answer as well Up vote also.*

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers! The formula works- thank you. Allthough I forgot to mention that the datasource will be updated once a week. Therefore I will have to sum by week, but with just one row per person.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @Ballefrans ,, please delete this post since it should appear as comments or post it as a New Question even !!